# What does the idiom "Yellow streak" mean?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning, chinese

My question is and I would like to know that at one time frequently used the idiom "YELLOW STREAK" now rarely used. The Idiom is used regarding, CHINESE PEOPLE".What does the Idiom mean?

In which contexts this idiom can be used.it seems the meaning is critical and disrespectful. In English novels written by Somerset Maugham, these set of words are sometimes found. Can the set of words be used as Applause?

Comment: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/yellow+streak

Comment: The term 'yellow' meaning 'cowardly' is probably not connected with the white-racist idea that East Asian people are coloured yellow. Anyone can be 'yellow' or have a yellow streak.

Comment: No, the idiom is not used regarding Chinese people. The idiom means *cowardly* and has nothing at all to do with racial epithets.

Comment: Nobody actually knows where 'yellow' meaning cowardly comes from. One theory is that a 'yellow' or 'yellow-bellied' (cowardly) person was being compared with a yellow-bellied frog. These sensible animals tend to rapidly hop away from danger.

Comment: @ Michael Harvey- The post is edited by @Laurel . One of the tags after editing is "Offensive Language" and the other is "connotation". The edits have sufficiently addressed my concern. So I have not commented, Rolled back second time or flagged. user-37920

Comment: There is a lot in Somerset Maugham's writing that is offensive to the non-European people he portrays in his stories set in Asia, and towards women.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey- James Hadley chase used the idiom in one of his thriller novels. user-37920

Comment: @user37920 More experienced users are attempting to help you with wording and formatting your question. Please don't undo their efforts.

Comment: I don't have a complete answer yet, but just off the top of my head, *The Caine Mutiny* (early 1950s novel and film) has a ship captain who is dubbed "Old Yellowstain" for dropping a dye canister and abandoning escort duties while under fire.

Comment: @Andrew Leach-I can't help adding few lines. I used to work in a branch office of a bank. The name of the branch is CENTRAL CLEARING BRANCH. The name of the branch has something to do with the IDIOM. A large number of persons who live in Kolkata believe this is a polished expression of the offensive language. user-37920

Comment: @user37920 - how could 'Central Clearing Branch' be offensive to anybody?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey- The bank branch is also known as SERVICE BRANCH OR CITY BACK OFFICE. I want to make clear that "yellow streak" and Simply "CENTRAL CLEARING" is SYNONYMOUS with a little imagination.BUT such discussion is skipped for the sake of sanity by almost all users. I myself have posted the question, so I after many evasive comments could not avoid making this comment. As separate words both idioms are ambiguous. user-37920

Comment: @user37920 -  'Yellow streak' and 'Central Clearing' are not 'synonymous', even with a very great deal of imagination. Why are you posting this nonsense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *yellow streak*, according to the OED (under "[yellow, adj. and n.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/231534)"), is

> *colloquial* (originally U.S.) a tendency towards cowardice (cf. sense A. 3b).

The first cited instance helpfully glosses the compound:

> 1892   Daily Picayune (New Orleans) 19 Sept. 3/1   They..said..that I could not hit hard, and that I had a ‘yellow streak’—meaning that I was afraid.

It is unclear why exactly yellow is associated with cowardice. Under A. 3b, the OED poses one possibility but admits uncertainty:

> The colour yellow was already associated with treachery in the Middle Ages, as is seen (for example) in the frequency with which Judas Iscariot is represented in medieval art as wearing yellow or having a yellow beard (cf. Judas-coloured adj. at Judas n. Compounds 2a); however, the origin of the specific association of the colour with cowardice, which seems to have arisen in American contexts in the later 19th cent., is unclear.